# Using a function in a function

Tags: r, dplyr

Using R and the dplyr package:

I have a function (lets call it *x*) that I wrote that takes in a **column** and a **data frame** as parameters and returns a **list** of summary information about the column. Now I want to create a new function (lets call it *y*) that takes in a **data frame** as a parameter and returns a **list** of information for each column (where the *keys* of the returned list are the column names, and the *values* are the summary information returned by the *x* function.

I have already written the x function, though I am having a hard time with the y function. I think it should look something like this:

```
y <- function(data_frame) {
  lapply(data_frame, x)
}
```

but I don't know where to go from here. I know I need to use *apply but I don't know how to write the y function so that the x function is applied to each column in my data frame. Can someone help with how my y function should be written differently?

Comment: You say that your `x` function takes a column and a frame, yet you only pass a column within `lapply`. Your question is a bit vague, though, to be able to provide much concrete recommendation.

Comment: I'm confused as to whether your question is a conceptual one, or if you are actually facing this? If its the latter, please share more info, including what function `x` looks like, and an example dataframe you're applying it to

Comment: Do you even need the y function? as r2evans said its a bit hard without a reproducible example but you possibly want `lapply(names(data_frame), x, df = data_frame)` assuming `df` is the name of the data parameter in x

Comment: As others have already commented you need to provide a reproducible example and show the output you expect. It is not exactly clear from your description what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Let's work with a real data set, the numeric columns of `iris`.

```
@library(tidyverse)
myIris <- iris %>% 
  select(- "Species")
```

For your *x* function, take the `mean`

```
x <- function(df, col){
  df[[col]] %>% mean()
}
```

Does it work?

```
x(myIris, "Sepal.Length")
[1] 5.843333
```

For your *y*

```
y <- function(df){
  tibble(KEYS = names(df)) %>% 
    mutate(VALUES = map_dbl(KEYS, ~ x(df, .x)))
}
```

Take it for a spin

```
y(myIris)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  KEYS         VALUES
  <chr>         <dbl>
1 Sepal.Length   5.84
2 Sepal.Width    3.06
3 Petal.Length   3.76
4 Petal.Width    1.20
```

Is that what you meant?